# Rails Catchall Route (app allows username in URL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple blogging app where a user's username is part of the URL (i.e. myapp.com/username). How do I create a catchall route for all usernames not found. Currently, an invalid username causes:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#show

undefined method `articles' for nil:NilClass
```

I'd like that to redirect to the 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

Write following function into your application controller

```
def not_found

  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')

end
```

Then write down something as below into your users controller

User.find_by_username(params[:username]) || not_found

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not the case in Production, which does indeed redirect to the 404 for invalid routes.